# Copying files on a remote system

Tags: linux, bash, unix, ssh, scp

Directories A and B are located on remote host H. File F is currently under directory A and needs to be copied to directory B.

Developer access is limited to local host L and any code written or executed must be on L. SSH access from L to H is permitted for user U but not in the interactive sense.

***The transfer needs to be done between two different locations on the same remote host administered by code that lives on the local host.***

There are two ways of completing the copy process known to the developer:

1. **scp U@H:A/F U@H:B**
2. **ssh U@H 'cp A/F B/'**

Both have been tested and known to work successfully. Which one is faster/better? Why? Is there a better alternative?

**EDIT:**
Added additional information, in bold/italic!

Comment: i think the second ssh command will be faster. You can run both with `-v` option, then you should see the different.

Answer (score 1):

We have ‍‍‍`rsync` command:

From your local machine:

```
rsync -chavzP --stats user@remote.host:/path/to/copy /path/to/local/storage
```

Or from the remote host, assuming you really want to work this way and your local machine is listening on SSH:

```
rsync -chavzP --stats /path/to/copy user@host.remoted.from:/path/to/local/storage
```